# Android device is already paired with printer, but still keeps asking for pin

Tags: android, bluetooth

I pair the device normally through the Android settings menu then attempt to connect it programmatically to a printer. I search through the paired devices, attempt to connect, and then it prompts me for my pin again. I'm trying to avoid having to type a password everytime a connection is made.

Here is the relevant code:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        String defaultPrinter = UserSession.getDefaultPrinter( context );
        BluetoothDevice preferredDevice = null;
        if ( defaultPrinter == null ) {
            //start activity regarding selecting a default printer
        }
        else {

            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
                if ( device.getAddress().equals( defaultPrinter ) ) {
                    preferredDevice = device;
                    break;
                }
        }

        UUID id = UUID.fromString( BLUE_TOOTH_UUID );
        try {
            selectedDeviceSocket = preferredDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( id );
            selectedDeviceSocket.connect();
            isConnected = true;
            return selectedDeviceSocket.getOutputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The connection will only happen if I re-enter the correct pin.

Answer (score 1):

Try to generate your own UUID:

```
private UUID generateUuid() {
String android_id = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext()
    .getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);
Log.i("System out", "android_id : " + android_id);

final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext()
    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
Log.i("System out", "tmDevice : " + tmDevice);
tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
Log.i("System out", "tmSerial : " + tmSerial);
androidId = ""
    + android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
        getContentResolver(),
        android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(),
    ((long) tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());

return deviceUuid;
}
```

and use it here:

```
selectedDeviceSocket = preferredDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( generateUuid() );
```

*Requires READ_PHONE_STATE permission